# modal win8 metro style website

Tags: php, html, windows-8, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I am writing a website based on the new windows 8 Metro style and this works ok.  I have a tile that links to a “Modal” on the same page that drops down from the top of the page and is like a light box where it darkens the background.

I now what to have a modal for each tile on my page (about 10) so I thought I could have a separate page called modal and pass the information over to it.

The problem I have is that the link below is calling the modal.php but is not going to the modal0 div.

Tile link:

```
<div class=" tile wide imagetext wideimage " role="button" data-toggle="modal" onClick="window.location.href='modal.php#modal0';">
```

Modal.php

```
<div id="modal0" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Am I doing something wrong as this is the first time I have played with the modals.

Comment: That doesnt give us much to go one. Some code would be nice.

Comment: Show us a minimal version of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, it's based on the scripts from http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/javascript.html#modals